# Laravel Passport: invalid_credentials, The user credentials were incorrect

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, postman, laravel-passport

I am trying to prove the authentication with Passport Laravel and it does not work. . . The error is in the screenshot of postman , when I try to create a user with postman gives me the error in the screenshot
**User.php**

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'user',
            'email',
            'password',
            'rol',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $dates = [
            'deleted_at'
        ];
    }
```

**api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::namespace('Api')->group(function() {
        Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
        Route::resource('productos', 'ProductosController')
        Route::resource('category', 'CategoriasController');
        Route::resource('gender', 'GeneroController');
});
```

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserStore;

use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \App\Http\Resources\UserCollection
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return new UserCollection(
            User::paginate()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UserStore $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(UserStore $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        $user = User::create($data);

        return $this->show($user);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\User $user
     * @return \App\Http\Resources\UserResource
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return new UserResource($user);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**UserStore.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserStore extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return !auth()->guard('api')->guest();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'unique:users,user',
                'max:255',
            ],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'unique:users,email',
                'max:255',
            ],
            'password' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
            ],
            'rol' => [
                'nullable',
                Rule::in([
                    'user',
                    'admin'
                ]),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

**UserCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection->map(function ($user) {
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'user' => $user->user,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'rol' => $user->rol,
                'created_at' => $user->created_at,
                'updated_at' => $user->updated_at,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

**UserResource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'rol' => $this->rol,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

- **Table Users**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD88y.png
- **Table oauth/clients**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOOio.png
- **screenshot Postman**:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuxxz.png
- **screenshot Postman**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0eJC.png

Answer (score 1):

Your passport table has wrong entries:

It should be

```
id -> 5
name -> Laravel Password Grant Client
secret -> //your key
redirect -> http://localhost
personal_access_client -> 0
password_client -> 1
```

For your reference:

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 0):

On the chance, someone has the same issue I had after upgrading from Laravel `5.4` to `5.5`.

I had to upgrade Passport from version `2.0` to `4.0.3`.